# How to pass through touch event to view below UINavigationBar when UINavigationBar is hiddened

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

My App have a full screen page (use `UINavigationController`). I have hidden the `NavigationBar` and the status bar, but I found that when hide the `NavigationBar` and the status bar, the touch event can not pass to the view below.

Do I need a custom `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use a custom navigation bar. Add a view over it and add a gesture for that view.